# Database Connection to live site

Tags: php, html, database, connection

I'm currently building an online booking form as a project and once the user hits the submit button it sends an email with the details to a specified email and stores everything in an database. Currently this is all working fine and well on a `localhost` set up.

I have a domain name with a current live website and when i upload this new website as an extra page it still preforms the sending of the email but won't load anything into my database.

I'm almost certain it's because my `php` script for the email/database is specifying `localhost` as the DB connection but how do i go about connecting it if i was to upload the webpage to my live domain.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Add the following at the top of you php script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` (comment when in production mode), then run your script and check for errors, specifically the line number. Most certainty  the error is one of the following:  is the mysql server running? Do you have permissions to write into that database? is the user/pass correct?

Comment: It is very possible that the database on your live server is also on localhost (the web-server itself) but you would need to have the same database installed / set up in mysql and you need a mysql user and password to access that database.

Comment: So who i host the website with is what i need to look for in regards to the mysql side of things? That's the only thing that's throwing me abit. Everything i looked for online so localhost.

Answer (score 1):

> Ask service provider for username and password and export sql file and upload then,ask them for run sql file and then try to connect database live.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: what can we do if want to connect it from our local machine ? bcz localhost refer our local machine

Comment: yes, localhost means local machine or 127.0.0.1, so whatever the IP of your server you can use instead of localhost